# Replace all occurrences

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a below data frame

```
x=c(1:21)
y=c(rep(0,2),rep(3,7),rep(1,12))
z=c(rep(1,17),rep(3,4))
table=data.table(x,y,z)
```

In this I need to replace all the 3's in the column y with the value of y where z value is 3 (which is 1 in this case).

```
table[, N := .N, rleid(y)]
table[, y := replace(y, N ==1, NA)]
table[N==1, y := zoo::na.locf(y)][, N := NULL]
```

I tried with  this but this one only replaces one occurrence not all .Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In this example, last 4 value of `z` are 3. Co-incidentally, all their corresponding `y` value is 1 here but what if the `y` value is not same meaning last 4 value are not 1, 2, 3 and 4? Which value would you take?

Comment: maybe something like `DT[y==3L, y := DT[z==3L, y[1L]]]` (used `DT` instead of `table` since latter is a very useful function) ? in addition, there are many possible scenarios that are not addressed in OP.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fifelse` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
table[, y := fifelse(y == 3, y[z==3][1], y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `replace` all `y` values where `y` is 3 with the first occurrence of `y` value where `z` is 3.

```
library(data.table)
table[, y := replace(y, y == 3, y[z==3][1])]
#Or similarly,
#table[, y := replace(y, y == 3, y[which.max(z==3)])]
```